# Picker's tint color is not updated when @State variable is changed

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, picker

When I have a `SwiftUI` `Picker`, whose color is based on a `@State` variable (`Color`) the Text color of the picker is not updated when the state variable changes.

Given the following code:

```swift
struct TestView: View {
    @State var selColor: Color = .red
    @State var selectedNumber: Int = 10

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Spacer()
            Text("Test String That changes color")
                .foregroundColor(selColor) // <-- works as expected
            Picker("Selected", selection: $selectedNumber) {
                ForEach([2, 4, 6, 8, 10], id: \.self) {
                    Text(String($0))
                }
            }
            .onChange(of: selectedNumber) { newValue in
                selColor = [Color.red, Color.blue, Color.green, Color.yellow, Color.blue, Color.brown][Int.random(in: 0..<5)]
            }
            .tint(selColor) // <-- sets the color upon initialisation but doesn't update afterward
            Spacer()
        }
    }
```

Whenever I change the picker's value, the text color's changed but the picker's does not.
In the example screenshot below, the text's color has changed to blue but the picker remained red.

[image: Text color changed, picker's didn't.]

Any ideas what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Where is `selectedNumber` defined? That's likely the cause of your issue if it's outside of your `View`

Comment: @jnpdx sorry for misleading, I forgot it out from the example. It is defined within the View, see the updated example. And it enters properly the `.onChange` modifier.

Comment: FYI onChange is not designed for transforming data, try a computed property to transform from selectedNumber to selectedColor

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I figured it out, though still not sure why the `.tint(_ Color)` modifier was not working, so I'm a bit afraid of this solution is being a workaround - but it works. The trick is to set the tint to `.white` and then connect the desired color state variable with the `.colorMultiply(_ Color)` modifier instead of the `.tint(_ Color)`.

Related code therefore:

```swift
        VStack {
            Spacer()
            Text("Test String That changes color")
                .foregroundColor(selColor)
            Picker("Selected", selection: $selectedNumber) {
                ForEach([2, 4, 6, 8, 10], id: \.self) {
                    Text(String($0))
                }
            }
            .onChange(of: selectedNumber) { newValue in
                selColor = [Color.red, Color.blue, Color.green, Color.yellow, Color.blue, Color.brown][Int.random(in: 0..<5)]
            }
            .tint(.white)            // <-- Set the base color to .white
            .colorMultiply(selColor) // <-- Here is the trick
            Spacer()
```